# Check if LuaTeX is running

Tags: conditionals, luatex

I want to check if my tex document is compiled with LuaTeX (or any other Lua TeX compiler).

The simple approach from the TeXbook is to check the `\directlua` macro against `\@empty`, like

```
\ifx\directlua\@empty{\errmessage{...}}\fi
```

If I'm running `luatex`, everything is fine. If I run `tex`, the compilation fails with my `\errmessage` -- fine. But if I run `latex`, my error does not occur, but the compilation fails because of the undefined `\directlua` environment. Which `\ifx` statement works for all TeX dialects? And why not the one which works fine with plain TeX, the one from above? 
Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE**

An solution for this is very easy, but I don't know if it's causing any problems in the future.

```
\ifx\directlua\pgf@gd@undefined@donotuse{%
  \errmessage{an error}\fi
```

works well with TeX and LaTeX. Is there a way which is more elegant and doesn't need any additional packages? Otherwise I will post this as answer.

Comment: // with expl3, \sys_if_engine_luatex

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\@empty` is defined in LaTeX, so your test fails. Why don't you use `ifluatex.sty`? It will work with plainTeX too,

Comment: @Matten I wouldn't use \undefined with LaTeX. \undefined is safe at the start of a format generation (context is using it there) but in a package it can fail as the probability that a user has defined it is quite high. Use a \veryunlikelythatsomeonewilldefineitcommand from the namespace of your package.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more direct answer that uses [iftex](https://ctan.org/pkg/iftex) (see Section 3):

```
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifLuaTeX
% ⟨material for LuaTEX⟩
\else
% ⟨material not for LuaTEX⟩
\fi
```

Answer (score 4):

How about [`iftex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/iftex)? it works fine in plain, and gives you some other useful macros.

It is also included in TeXLive.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
\ifcsname directlua\endcsname
  Yes, I am running LuaTeX
 \else
 Oh no, I give up
\fi
```

?

I guess that everybody is running etex with `\ifcsname` these days... There must be a drawback. But which?

Comment: This wouldn't work if somebody had tested for the `\directlua` primitive using `\@ifundefined` because that defines the command while checking. The `ifluatex` package also does a few sanity checks to avoid issues with nonstandard catcodes, old LuaTeX versions, etc.